# How to Avoid ProGuard obfuscation in Request Header Model in Retrofit 2 Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-webservice

1.without proguard Everything working fine. while enabling the Proguard, all the
header and body models are getting obfuscated.

2.Retrofit2 not able to pass data with model objects.

```
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 80
 {"a":{"a":"123","b":"***","c":"","d":"Data","f":"1.0"},"b":{"a":""}}
--> END POST (80-byte body)
```

below mentioned Proguard rules are already added in my code still getting same problem, kindly help me to fix this issue.

```
# Retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions


-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    *** get*();
    void set*(***);
}

-keepattributes Signature

-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
```

**Update:**
My Request header and data

```
RequestPojo requestPojo = null;
        try {
            requestPojo = new RequestPojo();

            RequestHeader requestHeader = new RequestHeader();
            requestHeader.setID("123");
            requestHeader.setNo("*******");
            requestHeader.setName("XYZ");
            requestHeader.setCode("ABC");
            requestHeader.setAge("1");


            /*Request DATA*/
            RequestData requestData = new RequestData();
            requestData.setData("Hai");

            requestPojo.requestHeader = requestHeader;
            requestPojo.requestData = requestData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When proguard is enabled then it will obfuscate all the request parameters. So to overcome this issue you have to do the following changes in your Request class:
Suppose this is your request class:

```
class DemoRequest{
         @SerializedName("name")//here this SerializedName will avoid obfuscate of variables
         private String name;
         .
         .
         .
}
```

Hope it will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

lets say your package name is com.example.android, and you have all your API request model classes in a package named 'requests'

then add this line to the proguard of your app module:

```
-keep class com.example.android.requests.** { *; }
```

add this line to all similar packages which might have the request models. So that those classes wont be obfuscated.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Use following.

```
# Retrofit
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform # Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor # Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8 # Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.

# OkHttp 3
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

Comment: hai,still same issue :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use following.

```
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.internal.** { *; }

-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

This will work for proguard.

Rest of the things not needed

Comment: hai,Still getting same issue